# Sitecore Speak UI : How to manipulate column value of List Control before displaying in list .

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am working in speak UI . I have list of items to display in list . But before that i have to check one column value and need to manipulate this value with a Icon to display . How can I implement this change in SpeakUI . Please help

Answer (score 1):

**Simple option:**

If the data you receive is directly relateable to the icon you want to display:

Set your `DataSource` on your `ListControl` to a `ListControl Parameters` item with your `ColumnField` items underneath (as outlined in [Sitecore doco](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/listcontrol) or [other blogs](http://mhwelander.net/2014/06/27/speak-for-newbies-part-2-where-does-the-data-come-from/)).  In the `HTMLTemplate` field for your column, you can use the value as the source of an image or CSS class with background image style.

```
<img src="{{YourField}}" />
```

or

```
<span class="{{YourField}}"></span>
```

where your span class styles your icon.

**More complex but customisable:**

I'm not sure which datasource you are using, but I am a fan of the [JsonDataSource by Anders Laub](http://laubplusco.net/creating-simple-sitecore-speak-json-datasource/) as it's very simple to use and customise (you only need to add 2 small files).

To your SPEAK renderings you add your `JsonDataSource`, and `ListControl` with Items property: `{Binding JsonDataSource.Json}` (and DataSource as required)

Then in the javascript for your page (defined in your `PageCode` rendering) you can add items to this datasource and customise as required:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/yourApiCall" + params,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.YourItems.length; i++) {
            app.JsonDataSource.add({
                Col1: data.YourItems[i][0],
                Col2: data.YourItems[i][1],
                Col3: data.YourItems[i][2]
            });
    }
},
```

Where Col1, Col2, and Col3 are the names of your columns, and YourItems is the array of items you are receiving from your ajax call.